# Parsing fields with special characters using Perl Text::CSV

Tags: perl

I am using the [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) module to parse lines into various fields from a tab-separated value file.

Examples of special characters in strings are

```
"CEZARY Å?UKASZEWICZ, PAWEÅ? WIETESKA","BÜRO FÜR"
```

My code goes as below:

```
my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get TSV file on the command line\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({sep_char => "\t"});

open(my $data,'<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";


while (my $line= <$data>) {

       if($csv->parse($line)){
            my @curr_arr = $csv->fields();

        }
} # end of while

close $data;
```

The above is some of the important parts of my code. The error I get is as follows:

```
cvs_xs error : 2026 - EIQ - Binary Character inside quoted field, binary off @pos 15
```

Comment: Important Note: The default behavior is to only accept ASCII characters. This means that fields can not contain newlines. If your data contains newlines embedded in fields, or characters above 0x7e (tilde), or binary data, you *must* set binary => 1 in the call to new (). To cover the widest range of parsing options, you will always want to set binary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, sep_char => "\t"});
```